# How to Get Cached HttpResponse (Apache HttpClient)

Tags: java, caching, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to compare the results of my old (cached) response and the new response I got from a certain request. But I have no idea how to get the cached response.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = CachingHttpClients.createMemoryBound();
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient(new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/path/to/file.json"));

InputStream fromUpstream = response.getEntity().getContent();
InputStream fromCache = ???;

// Compare fromUpstream and fromCache
...
```

What I’ve been doing up until now is use an `HttpCacheStorage` to do this, like so:

```
HttpCacheStorage cacheStorage = new BasicHttpCacheStorage(CacheConfig.DEFAULT);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = CachingHttpClients.custom()
    .setHttpCacheStorage(cacheStorage)
    .build();

String url = "http://www.example.com/path/to/file.json";
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient(new HttpGet(url));

InputStream fromUpstream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
InputStream fromCache = cacheStorage.getEntry(constructCacheEntryKeyFromUrl(url)).getResource().getInputStream();
```

And this works. But what I hate about it is the fact that the key for the cached entry is not-so-straightforward. I have to reconstruct the URL to include a port number (i.e. `http://www.example.com:80/path/to/file.json`).

I know that technically, I'm comparing `InputStream`s, but it'd be great if I can compare actual `HttpResponse`s.

Comment: HttpCacheEntry contains all element of the original response message: status line, response headers and response entity. What is stopping you from comparing those?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I've decided to just stick with what I did to access the response cache. I just thought I was doing something wrong because I had no way to "properly" generate the key for the cached entry. `CacheKeyGenerator` is package-private so there's that.

Comment: Raise a change request in JIRA and ask for a public interface exposing the functionality of CacheKeyGenerator